# How to automate the crawling without hardcoding any number to it?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've written a script using python with selenium to scrape names of restaurants from a webpage. It is working great if I hardcode the number of amount I want to parse. The page has got lazy-loading process and it displays 40 names in each scroll. However, my script can handle it. The only thing I would like to improve in my script is that I do not wish to hardcode the number; rather, I want it to detect itself how many are there and parse it successfully. Hope there is someone to help. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/pizza/Toronto')

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)

    links = [posts.text for posts in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@itemprop='itemListElement']//h3[@itemprop='name']/a")]

    if (len(links) == 240):
            break

for link in links:
    print(link)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the number of links has changed in the last iteration

```
num_Of_links = -1
num = 0
while num != num_Of_links:
    num_Of_links = num
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)

    links = [posts.text for posts in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@itemprop='itemListElement']//h3[@itemprop='name']/a")]
    num = len(links)
```

Comment: Thanks Guy, for your response. I tried just now with your suggested code. It gives 80 links only. You can check whether i have been able to follow your instruction properly by tracking the link. "https://www.dropbox.com/s/78gmeij5efwm8gn/Modified%20code.txt?dl=0"

Comment: @SMth80 Remove the break. The `while` condition will handle the exit from the loop.

Comment: I did that and found 40 links this time.

Comment: @SMth80 Do you have 40 elements in the beginning? Set `num_Of_links = -1` and `num = 0` (updated my answer accordingly).

Comment: Now it looks great. Get back to you shortly.

Comment: I just executed your script and found that works perfectly, Guy. One thing I noticed that different time it gives me different results. Btw, I increased the sleeping time before executing the code. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @SMth80 You are welcome :). What do you mean by it gives different results? there are missing links?

Comment: When i run the code for the first time I got 480 links then again running the same I got 560 links. This is what I meant. Thanks again.